# Cannot add a class to a button jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to change the color of button on click by adding a custom class and to show an image, the button is displaying image when clicked but not changing its color, why?

Links for my css and jquery:

```
<link href="static/dashboard/v3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="static/dashboard/v3/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="static/dashboard/v3/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="static/dashboard/v3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/dashboard/v3/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="static/dashboard/v3/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is the part where I have my buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="peso-1" class="btn btn-default pesito">5Kg</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="peso-2">30kg</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="peso-3">200Kg</button>
```

jQuery code to show images when buttons are clicked:

```
$('#peso-1').on("click", function() {
   $( "#img-bici" ).show();
   $( "#img-moto" ).hide();
   $( "#img-mc" ).hide();
 });
$('#peso-2').on("click", function() {
 $( "#img-bici" ).hide();
 $( "#img-mc" ).hide();
 $( "#img-moto" ).show();
});
$('#peso-3').on("click", function() {
 $( "#img-bici" ).hide();
 $( "#img-moto" ).hide();
 $( "#img-mc" ).show();
});
```

jQuery code to change the color of clicked button:

```
 $('.pesito').on('click',function(){
            $(this).addClass('colorpesos');
          });
```

css class

```
.colorpesos{
  background-color: #85c440;
}
```

Comment: Work fine **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/71/)**.

Comment: work fine with me either ,,, are you sure from importing jquery library ??

Comment: You have a relative path to style.css, this does not help us debug your classes. We need all of your styles.

Comment: if i put the code in jsfiddle works fine but running in my local server not

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I guess your peso1 button needs to exist before binding the click event.

Comment: You should get an error in the console as @ochi stated. Can you verify?

Comment: are you running the event binding code in onload event or jquery ready event? if not then jquery will not select any elements since they will not yet be loaded and so no binding will happen.